# background image not appearing within div

Tags: html, css

Background image isn't appearing in the .left left column. I have set .left with the css background-image but to no avail. Any ideas what is happening? I feel it is something small and it is bugging me.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left">
  </div>
  <div class="column right">
    <i class="fa fa-unlock fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h2> You're In </h2>
    <p> You deserve it. Unlock your welcome discount and be the first to know about leaked artwork & exclusive offers. </p>
    <h2> GET $20 NOW </h2>
<form class="omnisend-subscribe-form"><input type="text" class="omnisend-subscribe-input-email" placeholder="Email address" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; display: block; color: #a0a0a0; font-size: 16px; padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #cfcfcf; margin-bottom: 5px; outline-width: 0px; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;" /><input type="submit" value="I want my $20 off" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; display: block; color: #ffffff; font-size: 16px; padding: 8px; margin-top: 18px; background-color: #f47268; border-width: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 0px; outline-width: 0px; cursor: pointer;" /></form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  align-items: center;
  }

.column {
  text-align: center;

}

 .left {
  width: 50%;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0196/2898/2334/files/MU6.jpg?2930");
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .left {
    display: none;
  }
    .right {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code worked. The image isn't appearing because your .left empty, just set Height and Width to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify `height` on child elements of flex.

Also you should learn how to use the console (F12) to inspect elements for debugging.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  align-items: center;
}

.column {
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
 height: 380px;
 background-size: cover;
  width: 50%;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0196/2898/2334/files/MU6.jpg?2930");
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .left {
    display: none;
  }
  .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left">
  </div>
  <div class="column right">
    <i class="fa fa-unlock fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h2> You're In </h2>
    <p> You deserve it. Unlock your welcome discount and be the first to know about leaked artwork & exclusive offers. </p>
    <h2> GET $20 NOW </h2>
    <form class="omnisend-subscribe-form"><input type="text" class="omnisend-subscribe-input-email" placeholder="Email address" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; display: block; color: #a0a0a0; font-size: 16px; padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #cfcfcf; margin-bottom: 5px; outline-width: 0px; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;"
      /><input type="submit" value="I want my $20 off" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; display: block; color: #ffffff; font-size: 16px; padding: 8px; margin-top: 18px; background-color: #f47268; border-width: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 0px; outline-width: 0px; cursor: pointer;"
      /></form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give certain height to the left div as it does not have any element or content inside it to give it some height.

Also you can set background-size to cover or contain.

Try following code.

```html
 <html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

 <style>
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  align-items: center;
  }

.column {
  text-align: center;

}

 .left {
    width: 50%;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0196/2898/2334/files/MU6.jpg?2930);
    height: 400px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .left {
    display: none;
  }
    .right {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left">
  </div>
  <div class="column right">
    <i class="fa fa-unlock fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h2> You're In </h2>
    <p> You deserve it. Unlock your welcome discount and be the first to know about leaked artwork & exclusive offers. </p>
    <h2> GET $20 NOW </h2>
<form class="omnisend-subscribe-form"><input type="text" class="omnisend-subscribe-input-email" placeholder="Email address" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; display: block; color: #a0a0a0; font-size: 16px; padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #cfcfcf; margin-bottom: 5px; outline-width: 0px; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;" /><input type="submit" value="I want my $20 off" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; display: block; color: #ffffff; font-size: 16px; padding: 8px; margin-top: 18px; background-color: #f47268; border-width: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 0px; outline-width: 0px; cursor: pointer;" /></form>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Style:

```
 .left {
      width: 50%;
       height: 100vh;
       background: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0196/2898/2334/files/MU6.jpg?2930") center center;
       bacground-size: cover;
    }
```